# Flutter Release bundle or APK Crash on start, dlopen failed: library "libflutter.so" not found

Tags: android, flutter, lib

my debuggin apk is working perfacet, but the release crashing on start, in emulator Pixel 3a api 30

here is my error log in android studio

```
2021-02-25 10:20:52.264 6454-6454/? E/FlutterLoader: Flutter initialization failed.
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: library "libflutter.so" not found
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:123)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:193)
    at io.flutter.embedding.engine.loader.FlutterLoader.ensureInitializationComplete(FlutterLoader.java:178)
    at io.flutter.view.FlutterMain.ensureInitializationComplete(FlutterMain.java:78)
    at io.flutter.app.FlutterActivityDelegate.onCreate(FlutterActivityDelegate.java:145)
    at io.flutter.app.FlutterActivity.onCreate(FlutterActivity.java:91)
    at com.shoaibanwar.saray.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.kt:9)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8000)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7984)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1309)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3422)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3601)
    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2066)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
 Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: library "libflutter.so" not found
    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:1087)
    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:1008)
    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1664)
    at io.flutter.embedding.engine.loader.FlutterLoader$1.call(FlutterLoader.java:129)
    at io.flutter.embedding.engine.loader.FlutterLoader$1.call(FlutterLoader.java:123)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:923)
```

Answer (score 17):

Try changing the **abiFilters** in build.gradle at **android/app/build**

See documentation for [abiFilters](https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/abis#gc).

```
defaultConfig { 
    ndk { 
        abiFilters 'x86', 'x86_64', 'armeabi', 'armeabi-v7a', 'mips', 'mips64', 'arm64-v8a' 
    }
}
```

Only platforms specified in the abiFilters are built. If you are building for a local emulator on an x86 computer, you will need `'x86', 'x86_64'`.

Common issue: excluding `'x86', 'x86_64'` to prevent your app from being available to x86 android devices in the Play Store or bots, then being unable to run your app on your local emulator, while a physically connected android device builds fine.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to generate the **appbundle**, just added this in:

> ```
> flutter/android/app/build.gradle
> ```

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example"
    minSdkVersion 21
    multiDexEnabled true
    targetSdkVersion 30
}

signingConfigs {
    release {
        keyAlias [whatever]
        keyPassword [whatever]
    }
    debug {
        [whatever]
    }
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        ndk {
            abiFilters 'arm64-v8a', 'armeabi-v7a', 'x86_64'
        }
    }
}
```

inside *buildTypes* -> *release*:

```
ndk {
 abiFilters 'arm64-v8a', 'armeabi-v7a', 'x86_64'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this error trying to debug in physical Android device, just deleted .gradle folder in android/

Answer (score -1):

> add ndk abiFilters in android/app/build.gradle

```
defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.devsig.cloudauthenticator"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdk 32
        versionCode 4
        versionName "1.0.4"
        multiDexEnabled true
        signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        ndk {
            abiFilters "armeabi", "x86", "armeabi-v7a", "x86_64", "mips",
                    "mips64", "arm64-v8a"
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -7):

In my case I solved this by running 'flutter upgrade' from the command line.